# React PropTypes: range of numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, range, react-proptypes

Is there a better way to validate **if a number is inside a range**?

Avoiding to write

```
PropTypes.oneOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), you can define your customProps

```
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
  }
```

So for your case you can try the following

```
function withinTen(props, propName, componentName) {
  componentName = comopnentName || 'ANONYMOUS';

  if (props[propName]) {
    let value = props[propName];
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
        return (value >= 1 && value <= 10) ? null : new Error(propName + ' in ' + componentName + " is not within 1 to 10");
    }
  }

  // assume all ok
  return null;
}


something.propTypes = {
  number: withinTen,
  content: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired
}
```

Comment: You could also provide a currified function that would take a range as parameters so that you avoid hardcoded parameters in the function definition.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a sequence, You can use a smart ES6. :)

*[BTW, I believe the first answer is the most appreciate, this one is just **trick**]*

```
PropTypes.oneOf([...(new Array(10))].map((_, i) => i + 1))
```

---

**Explanation:**
This `[...(new Array(10))].map((_, i) => i + 1)` part will give to the sequence.

```js
// Sequence
console.log([...(new Array(5))].map((_, i) => i + 1))

// Spreading the Sequence numbers 
console.log(...[...(new Array(5))].map((_, i) => i + 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom Prop validator.

```
completed: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (props[propName]>=1 &&  props[propName]<=10) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
  }
```

Please refer the documentation for further details.

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [airbnb's extension to proptypes](https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types)  which support the `range` PropType

> range: provide a min, and a max, and the prop must be an integer in the range [min, max)
>   foo: range(-1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want pass and validate age between `age <= 18 && age >= 60`.

The below code will pass the value between the range other it won't return anything. I hope this this will help you and newcomers a lot.

In your functional component **App**,

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const App= (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am in the App Component!</h1>
      <p>Age : {props.age >= 18 && props.age <= 60 ? props.age : false}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
App.propTypes = {
 age : PropTypes.number
}

export default App;
```