# React propType specify allowed props value

Tags: reactjs

Is there a propper way to specify for the user of the React component that the prop value needs to be a number between e.g. 0 and 100?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React PropTypes: range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489434/react-proptypes-range-of-numbers)

Comment: ```PropTypes.oneOf([0,1,2,3,...,100])```  you can generate the list from a function

Comment: [AirBNB's `prop-types` library has a `range` type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airbnb-prop-types) you could look into.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a custom function to your propType:

```js
propTypes: {
  myProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (typeof props.myProp === 'undefined') {
      return new Error(
        'Required prop `' + propName + '` was not specified in `' + componentName + '`.'
      );
    }
    else if (props.myProp < 0 || props.myProp > 100) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid value for `' + propName + '` in `' + componentName + '`.'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also check if the typeof isn't an integer and throw an error @Chris

Comment: @AlfredAyi-bonte, indeed. One can add multiple "checks" here. This is only something to get OP started.

Comment: This answer helped me, but I also needed the ability to specify if it was 'isRequired' or not.  This link got me the rest of the way there.  basically you create a function that takes 'isRequired' as a param and returns different versions of the prop function: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9125#issuecomment-285531461